# How to structure JSON Action Schema

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I wanted an Autopilot bot to send its memory data to a webhook file of mine (which is in PHP) and in return (as a callback) just print a message saying "Received".
But every time, I get an error saying "It does not match with Action Schema."

So I was wondering if anyone could give me a nice example as to how to do this?

I've tried reading the ActionSchema.json file provided in the Debugger, but I couldn't understand it at all.

I have tried like this

```
echo '"definitions": {
    "say": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "strdfghing"
        }';
```

I want Twilio Autopilot to reply "Got it!" after it sends its memory events to a webhook file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

So you probably have your [Collect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#collect-properties) flow, where you can use the [Say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/say) verb to respond with "got it!" at the end in the [on_complete](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#collect-properties) of a [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#collect-properties). Your Autopilot task may look something like this:

```
"actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "collect_clothes_order",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "What is your first name?",
                        "name": "first_name",
                        "type": "Twilio.FIRST_NAME"
                    },

                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": "your-web-server-ie-a-twilio-function-maybe"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Then, in your [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage) (or another web server in the language of your choosing), you could receive the memory data (in this case, the first name that the user responded with), and return the `Say` containing "got it!":

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let responseObject = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);

    console.log(memory.twilio.collected_data);
     let first_name = memory.twilio.collected_data.collect_clothes_order.answers.first_name.answer;
    console.log(first_name); //collected data from memory
    responseObject = {"actions":[
        { "say": { "speech": "Got it!" } }
    ]};
    callback(null, responseObject);
};
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the code I wanted! Thank you very much